# How to Make combobox first item style as selected so that typing will overwrite that item

Tags: vb.net, combobox

What i wanted is after binding combobox, the first item ( first item will be always header like 'Select Item') need to be in selected style, means the blue back color and typing will overwrite that item (autocomplete starts then).

dropdownstyle is dropdown so that user can type inside combobox.

Wanted like this[image: wanted like this]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the combobox gets focus the text will be selected automatically.
If you want the combobox to get focus right after the binding you can use

```
ComboBox1.DataSource = oDataSource
ComboBox1.Focus()
```

Comment: +1. `When the combobox gets focus the text will be selected automatically.` Exactly, there is no need to implement this as custom behavior.

Answer (score 0):

There are two methods :

```
comboBox1.Focus();
```

or

```
comboBox1.select(0, comboBox1.text.Length);
```